# Changing LWJGL icons (taskbar and program)

Tags: java, image, lwjgl, javax.imageio, bytebuffer

I'm trying to change the taskbar's and the program's icon, but when I use the code I have the icon is just the default program icon. Here is my code:

```
public ByteBuffer loadIcon(String filename) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(filename));
    byte[] imageBytes = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(imageBytes);
}
```

and in my initialisation, I call:

```
Display.setIcon(new ByteBuffer[] {
            loadIcon("/icon16.png"),
            loadIcon("/icon32.png")
        });
```

What is wrong here?

**EDIT**

Have also tried this.

```
public void setIcons(String[] refs) throws SlickException {
    ByteBuffer[] bufs = new ByteBuffer[refs.length];
    for (int i=0;i<refs.length;i++) {
        LoadableImageData data;
        boolean flip = true;

        if (refs[i].endsWith(".tga")) {
            data = new TGAImageData();
        } else {
            flip = false;
            data = new ImageIOImageData();
        }

        try {
            bufs[i] = data.loadImage(getClass().getResourceAsStream(refs[i]), flip, false, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error(e);
            throw new SlickException("Failed to set the icon");
        }
    }

    Display.setIcon(bufs);
}

setIcons(new String[] {
                "/icon16.png",
                "/icon24.png",
                "/icon32.png"
        });
```

Have also tried without icon24.png. Neither works.

Comment: You might need to add a 24x24 version of your icon too.

Comment: Added a 24x24 version, didn't work

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the way you load the `imageBytes` and the `Display.setIcon` method checks if its a valid buffer and in your case its probably not. Maybe you should try a different way of loading them? Try this http://pastebin.com/fdb4Murh instead.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791654/taskbar-icon-with-lwjgl?rq=1

Comment: Have tried that, createBuffer() wasn't a recognised function though. Do you know which import this would use? I've tried looking it up but nothing has come up

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know that, already wondered what it was when reading it the first time. I assume its a similiar function like the one you are already using. Have you tried any other ways of converting your images to `ByteBuffer`s, have you tried it with different images, made sure the images are in the right directory?

Comment: I've tried all the other ways suggested on the question you link me, and another I found on a forum. If the images were in the wrong directory, the application would crash with a NullPointerException.

Comment: I am just trying to help and make some guesses. And if the images were in the wrong directory, it would throw a `FileNotFoundException` before the `NullPointerException`. Can you try using `getData` instead of `getRaster`?

Comment: byte[] imageBytes = ((DataBufferByte) image.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData();

Just tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: The [`Display.setIcon(ByteBuffer[] icons)`](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#setIcon(java.nio.ByteBuffer[])) JavaDoc states:

"The implementation will use the supplied ByteBuffers with image data in RGBA (size must be a power of two) and perform any conversions nescesarry for the specific platform."

Are you sure that your images (ie, your byte buffers) are all square and in RGBA format?